# Announcement: the MathStackExchange Blog is active, and Call for Content!

Tags: discussion, blog

## Announcement: We have a [blog](http://math.blogoverflow.com/)!

And in case you didn't notice, the standard links in the dropdown menu have updated. So now clicking here

[image: Click Here!]

takes you to the blog! This is an exciting time, as the blog is young. There's some content, but it [needs more](http://xkcd.com/741/)! And this is where you come in. We once asked who would contribute to the blog, and [some users answered](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13424/9754) (and about half or so actually wrote something). It's time again.

Are you interested in something, and think others would be interested too? Perhaps you've been looking for an excuse to find out more about an area of math you might not otherwise enter? I encourage you to follow your interests. [Do things, and write about it](http://www.mdswanson.com/blog/2013/08/11/write-things-tell-people.html). And do not feel pressured - contributing once, or just a few times, is perfectly acceptable.

So read the [blog](http://math.blogoverflow.com/) (the content ranges from high school to research math), and **if you're interested in writing** (or if you have an idea that maybe you'd like someone else to write about) then read the [blog faq](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13903/community-blog-faq) and come and chat in [the blog chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14206/the-blog-room).

We are also interested in having one or two additional community editors (in addition to [anorton](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23353/anorton)) who want to help. Let us know if you're interested!

Comment: This sounds excellent and I'm willing to contribute, but why not have a voting procedure on what types of articles people want? For example, I have three topics in high school math in mind (that I can write about) but I'm not sure which would appeal to the community the most.

Comment: @AhaanRungta Wait until mixedmath posts to confirm, but we could have people who want to write a blog post it here.  Then, the community could vote them in order.  Posts with a $>x$ vote count ($x$ to be determined) would then be written.  (And after written, reviewed, etc.)

Comment: I had posted content for this blog 2 months ago, but it seems to be lying there in the queue without any feedback from anyone moderating the blog. Sort of creepy for the content providers like me. I think there should be a timeline for feedback (say a month or so) depending on the number of reviewers and amount of content available in the queue otherwise content provider does not have any incentive.

Comment: Regarding the job of editing I can help with that at least for the high school and advanced high school stuff. I wont consider myself to be suitable for editing content on a higher level.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yikes!  Sorry about that.  :)  I thought for sure that I had marked it as "pending" (meaning it was ready for posting, and just needs a moderator to post), but evidently not...  It's now marked as pending.  **To all:** If something like that happens again, please ping someone on the blog team.

Comment: @AhaanRungta: that's an interesting idea. But I wonder where that would take place. I think meta would be a lousy spot, as the meta crowd isn't representative of the MSE crowd, nor representative of those interested in reading the blog. The blog chat room isn't particularly good either. Perhaps getting a sense through the main chat would be the best idea? I'm uncertain.

Comment: @mixedmath You bring up a good point. Perhaps start it in the Meta itself but make it a "global announcement" of some sort so that people who visit the main site can also see it?

Comment: Didn't we do this already? [14 people volunteered to deliver articles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13424/25554) and most of them didn't deliver. What will be different this time around?

Comment: @MJD: that post was made before there was a blog, and those volunteers were to initially populate the blog. It seems likely to me that some people may be inspired by seeing a current blog. In fact, some have been, and a new article has already come out of it. But more importantly, I wanted a meaningful post to point the event that shows up in the top right of the home page. We're experimenting, seeing how things go.

Comment: I am willing in helping out with writing some articles. :) However, I am having my Year End Assessments right now... Will only be free after the month of September... Two ideas I have (topics of Math that I personally enjoy) are complex numbers and their geometric/trigonometric applications; prime number research/Riemann Hypothesis.

Comment: If the blog publishes six articles between now and 11/26, I'll contribute another one.

Comment: re voting on article ideas there is already a [post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13569/what-sorts-of-posts-would-you-like-to-see-on-the-math-se-blog) for that. re MJDs comment about submissions/ volunteers: my blog was written promptly as volunteered, edited by anorton, but declined by the editorial committee on largely subjective and arbitrary style issues in a large chat runaround headed by MM & has also deleted (?) a comment of mine on the blog re editorial policy. am not happy with his exclusionary-rather-than-inclusive and verging-on-unilateral management style so far. :(